# Why do I get Error method has more than one entity. You must use only one entity parameter

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am developing a servlet for JAVA EE and keep getting this error "Error Viewerpage.index method has more than one entity. You must use only one entity parameter."

> 

```
@ApplicationPath("REST2")
@Path("/viewer")
public class Viewerpage extends Application {
private GlobalConfiguration globalConfiguration;
private ViewerService viewerService;

@GET
@Path(value = "/viewer")
public Response index(String filename, String page, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    // set headers before we write to response body
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);

    // render a page of a file based on a parameters from request
    renderPage(filename, response.getOutputStream());

    // complete response
    response.flushBuffer();
     String value = "redirect:index";
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(value).build();

}

private void renderPage(String filename, OutputStream outputStream) {
    String filepath = "storage/" + filename;

    // render first page
    MemoryPageStreamFactory pageStreamFactory = new MemoryPageStreamFactory(outputStream);
    HtmlViewOptions viewOptions = HtmlViewOptions.forEmbeddedResources(pageStreamFactory);

    Viewer viewer = new Viewer(filepath);
    viewer.view(viewOptions);
    viewer.close();
}
}
```

Any ideas what cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a resource method, you can only have *one* parameter that is the request entity. The parameter *without* any annotations is considered the entity body. All other parameters *must* have some kind of annotation that specifies what it is and what should be injected. If they are query parameters, use `@QueryParam`. If it is a path parameter, use `@PathParam`. If it some other non-Param injectable (that is supported) e.g. `HttpServletRequest`, then use `@Context`. Other supported "Param" injectable types are `@HeaderParam`, `@FormParam`, `@CookeParam`, `@MatrixParam`, etc.